# ld: library not found for -lSupport-bitcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, bitcode

I am not able to find why is this happening. Searched but no related issues found.

> ld: library not found for -lSupport-bitcode
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Message while building gives Link error on :

> Ld /Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xyz-gfpfhrpecsbpcucmbtbvnatnpnux/Build/Products/Staging-iphonesimulator/xyz.app/xyz
>
> ld: library not found for -lSupport-bitcode

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode custom build configuration causes "library/file not found" for static libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523690/xcode-custom-build-configuration-causes-library-file-not-found-for-static-libr)

Comment: @Lion : not sure. It was working on the same configuration build schemas before.

Comment: What is the bit code that you have set in build settings?

Comment: @User511: I have set bit-code to NO for target.

Comment: Are you opening workspace in your project?

Comment: Open the workspace instead of Xcode project. In build settings - set Build Active architecture Only to Yes. And see if it working.

Comment: @User511 No luck. Its not working .Same error :(